# What is a dictionary table in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have to build this retail site, and aparently all the properties info comes from a third party company. Everything looked fine, they sent me a .mdb file with all the tables (which convert to a .sql file), and later I get emailed with data to update those tables.

What confused me was the fact that a few of these tables already have values in them. And when looking at the documentation, it says that I will also get emailed 'dictionary tables'. It says: "These tables contain fixed values in reference to value tables".

I have googled and searched here at stalkoverflow but couldnt find an answer. What I read was something about 'sas' and 'proc sql' which I haven't heard before.

Could someone please explain me (or kindly point me to some understandable documentation) what this tables are (are they in fact tables?), and how can I use them to build my site? I also use Codeigniter, can I use active records on them? Or what would be the correct SQL to access that table? I'm pretty much lost here :(

I use Codeigniter 2.x and Mysql.

Thanks guys, I will be infinetely grateful for your help.

Comment: You should probably ask the third party company to clarify what they mean by the term dictionary tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two guesses:
a data dictionary provides information about tables in a database:
field names, field types, field sizes 
stored procedures associated with certain tables

OR

simply a fixed table that provides lookup or validation for a separate updatable table.

Comment: I agree, this is probably just the terminology they are using for reference data.

Comment: I got two types of tables on database. One is empty, and i will get emailed .txt files to update them daily. Another one already has data on them, for example a list of cities. For this tables that already have values on them, is what they are going to send me 'dictionary tables'. Which one could be?

Comment: In mySQL there exists a CHECK clause in CREATE TABLE or ALTER TABLE which limits the potential values for a particular field.  For example  the upload table could have this clause:

Comment: REVISION OF COMMENT: In mySQL there exists a CHECK clause in CREATE TABLE or ALTER TABLE which limits the potential values for a particular field.  For example  the upload CREATE TABLE could have this clause: CONSTRAINT myConstraint CHECK(myCityName IN ('NY','LA','BOS')) where myCityName reflects a field name in the upload table.

Comment: hmm I'm not sure if that's it. I found this link on dictionary tables http://www.sfu.ca/sasdoc/sashtml/proc/zsqldict.htm but don't know if that's it either, becauses it talks about 'sas' and 'proc sql' which I dont know what it is. Have you heard of this?

Comment: SAS is an analysis app for large datasets.  I suggest disregarding those terms. Your immediate concern is mySQL. From your description I still hold on to the view that my previous comment stands.  You are being given a table that limits values in an upate table.